# WordPress ошибки

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Пытаюсь развернуть готовый проект на локалхосте, но получаю вот такие ошибки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем проблема? как исправить?
Заранее благодарен за ответ

Comment: У Вас PHP 8 или выше? Плагины обновлены до последней версии?

Comment: @Simon php выше 8, сейчас даунгрейднул до 7^ то работает нормально, остались правда несколько ошибок но не критических, очень благодарен за подсказку)

Comment: Так-то желательно плагины обновить до последних версий, чтобы и с PHP 8 и выше тоже корректно работало.

Answer (score 0):

Если беспокоит отображение ошибок, то отключите их в php.ini

```
error_reporting = E_COMPILE_ERROR|E_ERROR|E_CORE_ERROR


display_errors = Off
```

Если же беспокоит причина их появления, то проверьте по каждой ошибке состояние. Видно, что не в порядке плагины (скорей всего не перенесены и требуют установки)